# Custom Attributes error an object reference is required for the non-static field method or property asp.net

Tags: c#, aop, custom-attributes

Hi i am trying to implement custom attributes to get rid of some duplicate code while implementing facing some issue.Below is my code for custom attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]    
public class XYZ : Attribute
{
    public XYZ(IDiscoveryClient client, RequestHeader requestHeader)
    {

    }
}
```

---

This the code how am calling attribute

```
public class test
{        
    DiscoveryHttpClientHandler _handler;
    RequestHeader requestHeader;
    string apiURI = null;

    public test(IDiscoveryClient client, RequestHeader requestHeader,)
    {
        _handler = new DiscoveryHttpClientHandler(client);            
        this.requestHeader =requestHeader;
    }

    [Utility.XYZ(client,requestHeader)]
    public async Task<List<AsOrderedBOM>> GetAsOrderedData(string[] salesOrderRef)
    {
        //some logic
    }
    //this is giving error an object reference is required for the non-static field method or property asp.net
}
```

Comment: You can't access instance members from attributes, because attributes are only part of the class metadata. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: there is some redundant code in business logic which i want to make as a attribute for that i need to pass parameters as mentioned above

Comment: Code in attributes doesn't get executed until you access them via reflection - If I were you I'd create a regular XYZ method instead, and call that from inside your method.